# CSS transitions not working after removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When applying some CSS to this component:

```
<div id="cart-circle">
      <div id="cart-content">
          <div id="cart-icon" class="text-bordered fa fa-shopping-cart"></div>
          <div id="cart-title" class="text-bordered animated bounceOutRight"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

The problem comes out after removing the class `open-cart-circle` from the div (with `cart-circle` class), which is added when the user clicks the circle itself. `open-cart-circle` tweaks the `height`, `width` and `border-bottom-left-radius` properties, performed by the animation:

```
@keyframes trigger-cart-circle {
  100% {
    height: 95px;
    width: 495px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 26%; }
}
```

and this is how `open-cart-circle` looks like:

```
.open-cart-circle {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-name: trigger-cart-circle;
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
}
```

So when `open-cart-circle` is added the animation begins and I want you to notice `animation-fill-mode` is intentionally put there in the code since I want the "circle" move smoothly (transitions with 0.5s) while opening and closing the side bar. Because **after closing the side bar twice, the CSS transitions seem not to work**. Why? I've just got stuck hours...

Here `cart-circle` must have transition:all because this "circle" should "softly" return to its original shape when closing:

```
#cart-circle {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border: 0.051px solid #333;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;   /*HERE*/
}
```

**EDIT**

Do `will-change` property have any point here for a possible solution?

Comment: Fixed the js errors and removed `$(body)` at the end: https://jsfiddle.net/ymvcuq9v/

Comment: Oh yes, that is the way how my original side bar actually works. I;m going to update the fiddle

Comment: Would it be considered as a bug? I couldn't find any solution outside

Comment: `will-change` is for performance optimization only. It does not affect functionality.

Comment: I can't find the problem but there is a good example http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/12/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you can see, the `transition` doesn't apply on the `animation`.

So the solution is simple, rename your `trigger-*` animations to `trigger-open-*` and create the corresponding `trigger-close-*` animations.

Then every time you add the `open-*` class, remove the `close-*` class.
and every time you remove the `open-*` class, add the `close-*` class.

Here is your jsfiddle fixed.
https://jsfiddle.net/pu5y8quz/

Comment: and so are you going to reward the bounty??